# When I Add Javascript It Displays A Blank Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to this site so I hope I am doing the correct format here!

My question is, I am "new enough" to HTML and today I wanted to start using some Javascript to make some fading transitioning images.... of course something had to go wrong, it's just my luck. So I went online and followed some tutorials and what I came up with is this:

Link To Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GW02CsJ1 (Couldn't Put In Code Because It Kept Giving Me An Error I tried To Fix For 20mins!)

So once I open this page, it's just completely blank, I left the page open for at least 5 minutes and nothing happens. One thing I don't know about is jQuery... What is this? I've also tried different browsers and same result happens. I've looked around but have not found anything useful, so any help at all would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Jquery is a javascript library. You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Sounds like a `<script>` tag issue. Make sure your javascript is enclosed in `<script>...</script>` tags.

Comment: I was a beginner once too and it is my opinion that JQUERY sucks for learning because it obfuscates the native javascript syntax, which is really very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have defined the variable `next` inside the if/else statements but after that, the variable visibility is lost.  Try defining it outside of it and then updating it/referencing it afterwards, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var active = $('#banners .active');
        var next;

        if (active.next().length > 0) {
            next = active.next();
        } else {
            next = $('#banners img:first');
        }

        next.css('z-index', '2');

        active.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            active.css('z-index', '1').show().removeClass('active');

            next.css('z-index', '3').addClass('active');
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Also, I tried fixing some of the typos...

**DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vkxp8kcg/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can see what you've changed but still, it stays on the first image and doesn't change....

Comment: I can see it working on the demo (follow the link) - I added different sizes to make sure I could tell the difference between them - do you now see it working in the demo?

Comment: I can see that working perfect alright! I think it's something to do with jquery? I just downloaded the jquery file, moved it to the same folder as my images and .html file itself and linked it inside src... After all that the images still don't change.

Comment: Managed to get it working! I just used: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a brackets in the `script` tab:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"</script>
```

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

About jQuery:
It's a JavaScript library that will help you write shorter code using its function. Also, if you are using it with your script tag, you need to have that in your code base, or you can use any CDN link like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With that done, you just need to have the images present at their defined location.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that. Now it just shows the first image, it doesn't transition to the next image at all, any ideas?

Comment: See my answer for transition fix

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's not going to work.
You're missing the required file jquery.js.
You can download the file from http://jquery.com/download/
But it probably requires more work to make that script functional.

BTW: jQuery is a frame work to make things 'more simple' than programming it in plain JavaScript.